# fetch() post 404 error

Tags: javascript, json, http, http-status-code-404, fetch

I'm writing a simple preact front end for a node.js app. I am trying to read data from a json file in my project directory, take some input from the user, then write it back to the file.

I can load the json file from my project directory using fetch()...

```
fetch('config.json');
```

... however when I come to write data back into the file, I get a 404...

```
fetch('config.json', {
    headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(this.state)
});
```

Any ideas why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A post request needs to be handled by your server, so you can't just post directly to a file.

If you're using Express, you can create a route for this. Something like:

```
app.post('/post-data', function(request, response){
  // get data and write to the file here
})
```

See: http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app